# fallback method not working in i18n-js with rails 2.3

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I am integrating I18n-js in a Rails application. The integration is working fine along with the translations.But the problem I am facing is that when the required translation is not present in a particular language , say for example I selected Afrikaans as my language then in that case the fallback method should execute showing me the translation present in the default language.But its not happening and I get the error

**[missing "af.credential_requests.add" translation]**

This surely means that the fallbacks method is not working.
Though I have

```
I18n.fallbacks = true;
```

in my I18n-js. Please help.
I have my default locale set to "en"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you set `I18n.defaultLocale` correctly